# Should I include Display Name as App Store Keyword when different than App Title?

Tags: ios, seo, app-store, keyword

For example, say my App Store description is Titled: "Big Bobs Bowling". But due to space restrictions, the bundle display name (what is displayed under the icon when installed) has no spaces and is "BigBobsBowling".

I understand that the App Store description Title gets included in the App Store Search. But would it be a good practice to include "BigBobsBowling" as a keyword, in the event someone searches based on seeing the installed icon? Or does the search function somehow account for this? I am keeping in mind that I do not want to waste valuable keyword characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, you don't need to add the keyword `BigBobsBowling` in your App Store Keywords. If someone searches that term your app will be found.

For info, one of my app is titled `Market Impulses` but if I search the term `MarketImpulses` I found it (I didn't define that term as a keyword).

You can focus your remaining keywords characters to your ASO :-)